# Can RestAssured handle session IDs within headers other than the standard "Set-Cookie" header?

Tags: rest-assured

I'm developing a Restful Spring application that uses Redis for session management.

The session token is returned by the application within a header by the name **x-auth-token**

So eventually, the response would have the following header\value:

```
x-auth-token: 9e018f74-fc50-461f-b979-a2a3369c1ab6
```

How can I configure **RestAssured** to read the **x-auth-token** header value when it's first returned from the server and send it with every successive request ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RestAssured.sessionId="sessionID"
```

The above line sets the default session id value that'll be used for each request.

Take a look @ [JavaAPI](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.1) and [docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage)

Comment: Thank you but this configures the name of the cookie variable in the `Set-Cookie` header. But I need to configure RestAssured to get the session ID value from a different header other than `Set-Cookie` without a variable name because the session ID value exists without a variable name as shown in my question..

Comment: This might help you `io.restassured.config.SessionConfig.SessionConfig(String sessionIdName, String sessionIdValue)`  Take a look @  JavaAPIDocs - http://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.1